# A Push Segue within a Subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

Is it possible for a push segue to happen just inside a subview?

I have an ipad app, I have a small subview in the lower left corner. Is it possible to just do the push segue just inside the bounds of my subview?

I'm trying it now, but when I do a segue, it displays the destinationVC in the entire screen.

Would anybody have any idea on how to do this?

I also cannot find questions similar to this in stack overflow, probably because I don't have the right words...

Comment: may be u can set pushed view controller's frame in init method of pushed view.

Comment: hello there @RohitDhawan, would you be able to provide some code to help me out? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
UIViewController *obj = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *viewCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];

[subview addSubView:viewCtrl.view];
NewViewController *objww = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[viewCtrl pushViewController:objww animated:YES];
[objww release];
```

u can try this and do what ever changes are required. `NewViewController` is u r pushed view controller whom u want to push.

Comment: hello Rohit, I'm not sure if I understand this code correctly. What is the subview here? I'm imagining that I have a UIView within which I'll put a view controller. I don't see that here. :)

Comment: UIViewController *obj = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *viewCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];